# PHP session is not storing Laravel file Upload object values

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to save the data of Laravel file upload in session. but it is not saving.
On file upload action I am recieving data from `$request->myfile`. Data format is

```
Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile Object
(
    [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
    [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => po10-jn.jpg
    [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => image/jpeg
    [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 35658
    [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
    [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /tmp/phpshpEIc
    [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => phpshpEIc
)
```

I want to save this whole object in session but it is not saving. Is this is any-other way to store this data in session.

Actually In my case it is multiple image upload and I want to save all images in session in the form of array.

Comment: _“Why PHP session is so weak”_ - quite a bold statement, for such a weak question ... Please go read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Sometimes small issues become a huge problem. @CBroe please answer if you have answer

Comment: @both - everyone chill.  We all get frustrated.

Comment: _“I want to save this whole object in session but it is not saving”_ - does your question currently show _anything_ of your attempt to store anything into a session? Nope, it doesn’t.

Comment: @Tarek we are chill :P

Comment: @RizwanRana ok great.  So, I posted about cache being an option - is it helpful, or should we keep looking for another solution?

Comment: My guess: You most likely simply haven’t analyzed the problem properly. Storing this object itself into the session should pose no specific problem per se ... but if you neglected to move the uploaded file from the temp directory someplace else while processing the request, then of course it will be removed after the script instance processing the upload is finished.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative if sessions are not enough...

```
Cache::put('key', 'value', $minutes);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/cache

Comment: I also checked with Cache and It is showing error "Serialization of 'Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile' is not allowed"